# Is it possible to disable dragging editors between windows in an Eclipse RCP application?

Tags: eclipse-rcp

I have an Eclipse RCP application which allows the user to open multiple windows. Within each of these, I have a bunch of editors which extend `org.eclipse.ui.part.MultiPageEditorPart`.

By default, the platform seems to allow the user to drag and drop my editors between Windows. This is potentially useful, but at the moment my app has certain assumptions about which window code is being executed from, and moving editors around like this can violate those assumptions.

Is there a facility in the Eclipse RCP to disable drag and drop of editors betweeen windows? Currently we're based on Eclipse 3.7, but we're aiming to move to the 4.x series very soon, so I'll accept an answer for either.

Comment: Looks like there is already an Eclipse bug open: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386250

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lack of answers suggests 'no'. Eclipse bug: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=386250